# Can not connect to Postgres db from another system

Tags: postgresql

I have configured my listen_address in postgressql.conf to '*'

```
             listen_addresses = '*'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
```

also added the required changes in pg_hba.conf

```
     host    all     postgres    192.168.1.85/24     trust
     host    all     postgres    ::85/128    trust
```

Still when I tried to connect it from the remote system I could not connect. Is there any other configuration that we have to do to connect the the remote system db?

Error Messages

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
   Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)   
 Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
  Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Error Message  
        could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Comment: Posted the error message that i got

Comment: I don't know if this will help but for correctness sake change 192.168.1.85/24 to 192.168.1.0/24, from 85 to 0. What host is this on? Linux, FreeBSD. Can you ssh from another host? What does 'netstat -na|grep 5432' say?

Comment: no i have tried this earlier,But its not working

Comment: Did you restart the server? Did you define an exception in your firewall?

Comment: i have restarted the server.and added all the exception still the same.

Comment: Can you add the JDBC URL you are using?

Comment: I am sorry i could not able to get your point ? where should i add my jdbc url

Comment: Divide&conquer: start by checking (nmap, telnet, psql; all on port 5432) if the server is visible from the client side. If that is the case,  your java/hibernate config must be wrong. And: inspect the logfiles on the server side.